# Hibernate get value of CollectionOfElements Map

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

Have a Hibernate `CollectionOfElements` `Map<String, String>` mapped using the `CollectionOfElements` annotation inside object `A`. I wish to just get the value of Map by joining the `A` and the associated Collection upon some where condition. Would highly appreciate if anyone can throw more light on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `Map<String, String>` attributes within object `A`, below HQL can get you the value of Map.

```
SELECT elements(t.attributes) FROM A as t INNER JOIN t.attributes as aAttributes
WHERE CONDITION='XYZ'
```